# Add custom response header with Rack-cors and Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, rack-cors

I'm developing a Ionic(Cordova) app with a Ruby on Rails API.
I want to use response headers to return a token after login.
I'm using `rack-cors` gem to make Cross Origin Request work:

## application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_after Rails::Rack::Logger, Rack::Cors, :logger => Rails.logger do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '/api/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :put]
      end
    end
```

and grape gem to manage my API routes.
But i can't find a way to add a header to my response since i added `rack-cors`.

I tried this:

```
header('Access-Token', user.token.key)
```

But it doesn't work. Whatever i do i end up with those headers:

> {cache-control: "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate", content-type:
> "application/json"}

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: can u add these to application_controller.rb and remove your current protect_from_forgery. add `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format != 'application/json' }
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }`

Comment: if yr working locally and calling rails api, it should not give you rack-cord as i know. Im just not experienced with cordova.

Comment: Indeed i'm working locally. i tried to change my protect_from_forgery as you suggested, but it gives me the well known 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Comment: And ionic can be emulated in my browser, just so you know, so it's pretty much an Ajax request that i'm doing

Comment: http://localhost:3007/api/login

Comment: what r u using for login devise ?

Comment: yes i'm using devise

Comment: if devise, use this one `https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth` it will be totally fine as i know.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `gem 'devise_token_auth'`

Also, i had this configuration in application.rb.

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
          :headers => :any,
          :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
          :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: Just pointing that the custom header needs to be lower-cased when declared in the `expose` key.